# Does wxWidgets have the equivalent of Qt's QWebChannel?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Qt's [`QWebChannel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebchannel.html#details) allows communication between the app containing the `QWebEngineView` and the javascript running inside of it. Does wxWidgets have a counterpart to `QWebChannel`? If not, what's the next best alternative?

Comment: Do not use the Qt tag since the Qt community will not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly `QWebChannel` allows to do, but the only way to communicate with JavaScript running in `wxWebView` is by using [RunScript()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.2/classwx_web_view.html#a4ca6c6e5c1c5b80dcbee725ef9fd0240) function which was extended with `output` parameter in 3.1.1, i.e. you can execute some JS in the context of the page and get back the value returned by it.